# ModelSerializer and ModelViewSet in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In DRF, we can use `create/retrieve/update/destroy/list` methods in `ModelViewSet` to handle GET, POST, DELETE, PUT request. and there is another set of methods in `ModelSerializer` namely create and update methods. Under what condition should I favor methods in `ModelSerializer` over those in `ModelViewSet` and viceversa? What is difference in create and update methods in ModelViewSet and ModelSerializer?